# Code is not executed

Tags: asp.net

Question from beginner. Why code <%= System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() %> is not executed in ASP.NET. Could anyone explain why it do not work?

```
<input class="input" name="url" id="url" type="text" runat="Server" style="width: 650px" onblur="this.value='<%= System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() %>'" />
```

Comment: All answers provided below are correct, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because of `runat="server"`. Either you generate the "onblur" attribute in your code-behind code, or you remove the "runat" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Probably related to it being runat=server, and asp.net might not put everything together correctly. Either don't have runat=server or move the javascript to a file or script block.

Answer (score 0):

change your input to:

```
<input class="input" name="url" id="url" type="text" runat="Server" style="width: 650px" onblur="setValue(this)" />
```

and add a js function in script tag at the bottom of your asp.net page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setvalue(txt){
var dt = '<%= System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() %>';
txt.value = dt;
}
</script>
```

This will work fine.